# Unhandled promise rejection firestore

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I don't quite have the promises down I make. Anyway, I am reading a list of rows in a mysql table, then upon writing into Firestore I want to update a count of a "related" record. Basically aggregate counts.

Here is the start:

```
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(body);
            //console.log(data);

            var allObjects = data.resource;
            var obj = {};


            for (j = 0; j < allObjects.length; j++) {
                var records = [];
                var record = allObjects[j];

                //FireStore
                var db = admin.firestore();
                var docRef = db.collection(toCollection).doc(record.nfCode);
                var rec = docRef.set(record);

                addCounts(docRef);


            }

            res.render('index', {title: 'Load Table'});

            offset = offset + limit

        } else {
            return res.send(body);//
            //res.render('index', { title: 'Error' });
        }
    });
```

Then here is addCount:

```
    function addCounts(docRef) {

    // In a transaction, update the aggregate totals
    var db = admin.firestore();

    return db.runTransaction(transaction => {
        transaction.get(docRef).then(res => {

        var brandRef = db.collection('brands').doc(res.data().brandNFCode);
    var transaction = db.runTransaction(t => {
        return t.get(brandRef)
            .then(doc => {
            if (res.data().glutenFreeYN == "Y") {

        var glutenFreeCount = doc.data().glutenFreeCount + 1;

        var setWithOptions = transaction.set(brand, {
            glutenFreeProductCount: glutenFreeProductCount

        }, { merge: true });


        return setWithOptions;

    }
});
})
.then(result => {
        console.log('Transaction success', result);
        // return nil
})
.catch(err => {
        // console.log('Transaction failure:', err);
        return nil
});

})
})
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? And where is my error coming from?

```
Auth error:Error: socket hang up
(node:90050) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: socket hang up
```

Comment: You aren't [`.catch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch)ing.  Are you asking how to fix the unhandled part or the socket hang up part?  In fact it doesn't look like you are doing anything with the Promises that calls to the firestore API probably returns.

Comment: This is gonne be a lifesaver, add this somewhere: process.on('unhandledRejection', r => console.log(r)); and check your logs.

Comment: You are calling `brand.set(...)` inside your transaction but instead you need to call `transaction.set(brand, ....)` otherwise the set is not part of the transaction.

Also you should `return setWithOptions` at the end to make sure the transaction waits for the set.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong with your `addCounts` function that may be causing this:

```
function addCounts(docRef) {

    // In a transaction, update the aggregate totals
    var db = admin.firestore();

    return db.runTransaction(transaction => {
        return transaction.get(docRef).then(res => {

                        if(res.data().glutenFreeYN == "Y"){
                            var glutenFreeProductCount = res.data().glutenFreeProductCount + 1;

                        }
                        if(res.data().vegetarianYN == "Y"){
                            var vegetarianProductCount = res.data().vegetarianProductCount + 1;

                        }
                        if(res.data().dairyFreeYN == "Y"){
                            var dairyFreeProductCount = res.data().dairyFreeProductCount + 1;

                        }
                        if(res.data().organicYN == "Y"){
                            var organicProductCount = res.data().organicProductCount + 1;

                        }


                        // LOOK HERE!!! You had brand.set()
                        // this version uses the transaction
                        var setWithOptions = transaction.set(brand, {
                            glutenFreeProductCount: glutenFreeProductCount,
                            organicProductCount: organicProductCount,
                            vegetarianProductCount: vegetarianProductCount,
                            dairyFreeProductCount: dairyFreeProductCount

                        }, { merge: true });

                        // LOOK HERE!! Make sure to return the 
                        // set operation
                        return setWithOptions;

                });

                // I removed the .catch() here as it will obscure 
                // errors. You can catch the result of addCounts.
    })
};
```

Comment: Ok I added trying to get the Brand... boom

Comment: (node:45168) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 18): Error: The referenced transaction has expired or is no longer valid.
(node:45168) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 19): Error: You must return a Promise in your transaction()-callback.

Answer (score 1):

Was running into this issue and spent over an hour trying to figure it out. Make sure your system time is synced properly. My time was correct, but my time zone wasn't so the system UTC time was out of sync.

To correct on Windows 10, go to Settings -> Time & Language -> Date and Time -> Sync Now